# How to understand solar and lunar eclipse?

Tags: belief, practice

- Are there any elements/materials which remain unaffected by the eclipse?
- Why do we put dharba/dried grass on eatables? Why & how they remain unaffected/unperished by the protection of dharba.

I don't know much about the prohibitions taken during & after any eclipse.

- Should the stored water & cooked food be thrown away after the eclipse?

I live in a city so, if all the stored water is thrown away then how can I take bath after the eclipse?

Comment: To my understanding..Yes! In absence of sunrays (indirect sunrays through moon), bacteria and other microorganisms will grow up rigorously, so we should thrown them out. But if dharba(special dry grass) is placed on them, they need not be thrown out. It is said that few elements like water(not sure on the complete list) need not to be thrown out. they remain uneffected. Taking bath before-after-during the eclipse is considered to be   very holy it brings us the punya of taking bath in holy rivers like ganga, yamuna..